# Marvel's Spider-Man: Miles Morales; Explanation for bio-electrical energy system's chemical formula and link to NuForm

Tags: marvel, video-games, spider-man, science, miles-morales

This is a screenshot from Marvel's Spider-Man: Miles Morales on PS4. The chemical formula is captioned as "Bio-Electrical energy system; * chemicals that interact w/ nuform" and was found on a whiteboard at Roxxon Corporation who designed NuForm, an experimental energy source that emits blue-white energy and is contained within clear cylindrical containers.

[image: Chemical formula]

Its primary characteristic is its potential to serve as a powerful and long-lasting energy source, capable of powering a city for 500 years.
Can anyone make sense of this chemical formula; how plausible is it? Are these just all the chemicals that interact with NuForm as captioned?

Answer (score 3):

It's not even a coherent chemical formula: there's hydrogens with two bonds, carbons with two bonds, oxygens with four bonds, there's a hydrogen apparently bonded to one of the single bonds of a benzene ring rather than to one of the carbons, a nitrogen apparently stuck in the middle of another, a random e pretending to be an element elsewhere...not as a free electron, but somehow hanging out with a couple carbons and an oxygen attached to another 6-member ring.

It looks like the result of someone copying the appearance of some organic chemical structures, without understanding how the parts went together.